# Remove automatically applied namespace in php's SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, dom, soap, xml-namespaces

I am trying to create a SOAP request for a paypal express checkout with SimpleXML. However, I am experiencing a behaviour I don't yet understand.

The envelope and its header are generated this way:

```
$envelope = new \SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:ns1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"
        xmlns:ns2="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"
    />
');
$header = $envelope->addChild('SOAP-ENV:Header');
$requesterCredentials = $header->addChild('ns2:RequesterCredentials');
$credentials = $requesterCredentials->addChild('ns1:Credentials');
$credentials->addChild('ns1:Username', 'foo');
$credentials->addChild('ns1:Password', 'bar');
```

Which yields the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                   xmlns:ns1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" 
                   xmlns:ns2="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:RequesterCredentials>
            <SOAP-ENV:Credentials>
                <SOAP-ENV:Username>foo</SOAP-ENV:Username>
                <SOAP-ENV:Password>bar</SOAP-ENV:Password>
            </SOAP-ENV:Credentials>
        </SOAP-ENV:RequesterCredentials>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Every node is now prefixed with `SOAP-ENV`, which is not what I want. Only the root node and header should be prefixed with `SOAP-ENV`, the other tags should get the defined namespace prepended in `addChild()`.

The desired output should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:ns1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"
                   xmlns:ns2="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns2:RequesterCredentials>
            <ns1:Credentials>
                <ns1:Username>foo</ns1:Username>
                <ns1:Password>bar</ns1:Password>
            </ns1:Credentials>
        </ns2:RequesterCredentials>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: To explain what happens, SimpleXML uses the namespace of the element as a default namespace. You append a new element node without the defining the namespace, SimpleXML uses its default namespace. The prefixes get optimized so it gets unified to the `SOAP-ENV` prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`addChild`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) takes the namespace as the third parameter:

```
$requesterCredentials = $header->addChild('RequesterCredentials', null, 'urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI');
$credentials = $requesterCredentials->addChild('Credentials', null, 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents');
$credentials->addChild('Username', 'foo', 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents');
$credentials->addChild('Password', 'bar', 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents');
```